# Xamarin TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset throws NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono

I'm trying to run this code:

```
_deviceTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(systemNow.ToDateTimeOffset()).TotalMilliseconds
```

but got an exception

> Unhandled Exception: System.NotImplementedException: The method or
>   operation is not implemented. at System.TimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset
>   (DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/2098/3efa14c4/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/TimeZoneInfo.cs:669

<del>I find mono sources with GetUtcOffset and NotImplementedException: [mono github](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/TimeZoneInfo.cs#L739).</del>

How can I get utc offset for my timezone if TimeZoneInfo can't do this?

---

## Fixed: [PR](https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/2649)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of @Übercoder answer I find a solution:

```
_deviceTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(systemNow.ToDateTimeOffset().UtcDateTime).TotalMilliseconds;
```

I use UtcDateTime instead of DateTime because DateTime ignore offset and returns 'Unspecified' time whereas UtcDateTime converts DateTimeOffset to UTC and I able to get correct timezone offset.

Answer (score 0):

mono does appear to have the `GetUtcOffset(DateTime dateTime)` implemented. So why don't you just use that instead:

```
_deviceTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(systemNow.ToDateTimeOffset().DateTime).TotalMilliseconds;
```